# How to translate "keep <something>" (as opposed to give it to someone or give it away)

Tags: single-word-requests

How should one translate the English verb "keep" in the meaning of **not giving something away** or not giving it to someone else?

Examples:

> Keep the change!

(Implied: Don't give it back to me.)

> She donated all her money, but kept the diamonds.

(Unlike the money, she didn't give the diamonds away.)

> Keep your drink, just give me the money.

— [U + Ur Hand](https://youtu.be/YUtHjOvPKT0?t=57) by P!nk

(Implied: Don't buy (and give) me the drink, give me the money you'd spend on it instead.)

Answer (score 2):

> How should one translate the English verb "keep" in the meaning of not giving something away or not giving it to someone else?

In that specific sense you could use:

- `*konserv/i`, laŭ PIV: `Ne perdi, plu posedi, havi ankoraŭ`

For example (from Tekstaro):

```
 Konservu viajn ŝparaĵojn; mi liveros al vi la tutan monon,
```

```
 ke ili povas tute trankvile konservi por si la liton,
 ke ŝi tiel same volonte kuŝas en la tirkesto.
```

```
Nun mi tre volus konservi la duan, kiu ankoraŭ restis al mi
```

- Another possibility is `*gard/i`
  (and the already mentioned `*ten/i`).

It depends on how you perceive the action. Is keeping something also protecting it or avoiding its disappearance? Then `gardi` might be the right translation. See this sentence from Zamenhof:

```
Amu Antonon, sed gardu vian monon. (proverbo)
```

- If you only want the *"not give (usually something that you should have given or you risked losing)"* meaning then you have `reten/i`:

> Konservi ĉe si ion, kion oni devus doni, vendi ks:

Comment: Is there a verb that just and only means "not give", without any implication of whether the thing is also preserved / protected or guarded?

Comment: I think in that case `reteni` could be used. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

La vorto «[teni](http://vortaro.net/#teni)» sonas taŭga:

> * **ten/i** (tr)
>
> […]
>
> **2** (iun) Restigi senŝanĝe en iu loko aŭ stato, malhelpante la
> foriron aŭ liberiĝon:  *teni iun en malliberejo*;  *teni birdon en
> kaĝo*;  *iru, iru, mi vin ne tenas!*;  *teni la amason en spirita
> sklaveco*;  *amu edzinon plej kore, sed tenu ŝin bonmore*;  teni la
> landon en malĝojo;  (f) *la ŝnuroj de lia peko lin tenos*;  *lia
> promeso tenas lin*;  *lia fianĉiĝo tenas lin malproksime de ĉiuj
> diboĉaĵoj*;  *la febro lin tenas*;  *mi estas tenata de miaj okupoj*.

Comment: Doesn't this meaning of "teni" imply to actually hold the object, i.e., prevent or limit its movement? What if something is being kept in one's possession without such restriction?

Comment: Indeed _teni_ means more "to keep something in a place". _Teni sian monon en la monujo_ : to keep one's money in one's wallet. While that is literal holding, you can use _teni_ also figuratively, see the quoted example _Iru, iru, mi ne vin tenas!_: Go, go, I'm not holding you back/keeping you from going/preventing you from going.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is ***restigi***:

> PIV **3** Lasi, ke io apartenu al iu: *nur prunti, ne restigi al si!*
>
> PIV **4** Lasi stari, ne forigi, konservi: *la venonta tago restigos
> al ili nek radikon nek branĉon*.

Comment: Isn't this kinda the reverse? ("not take <something> from <someone>" / "not take <something> away" instead of "not give <something> to <someone>" / "not give something away"?)

Comment: I wouldn't say the exact reverse, but you're right, _restigi_ doesn't mean "to keep something". My reading of the examples in PIV is more like "to leave behind oneself". _Libroj estis ĉio, kion lia patro restigis al li_ (…left to him) or _la akridoj formanĝis ĉion, kion restigis la hajlo_ (…remained after the hail).

Comment: I think that _restigi al si ion_ may be translated as _to keep something_. The Spanish-Esperanto Dictionary by F. de Diego gives the following example: _li restigis al si mian libron_ = _se quedó con mi libro_ [he kept my book].

Comment: @Vidamuzo, while ultimately the result is the same, the book stayed by him, I see a nuance difference. I think this way: _resti_ : to stay → _restigi_ : to make be-stayed i.e. to leave (behind oneself), which I see as a more passive act (just not giving something away) than actively keeping something. So _li restigis al si mian libron_ : he left to himself my book i.e. kept it by not making an effort to return it.

Comment: @Juha Metsäkallas: No doubt there's a nuance difference. Personally I prefer _konservi_ but thought this other option was worth mentioning, as it may work sometimes.